# What does error "E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!" mean?

Tags: android

i try to run my application  but it gives the following error:
"E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!" 
what does it means?and how can i overcome it?

Comment: I have the same problem and no solution!

Answer (score 1):

This issue maybe because of not providing internet permission. Try adding this line in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case was that I needed to add permissions in the in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle Developer options off/on and USB debugging. It worked for me.